# Parallax not working in Chrome or Safari

Tags: jquery, html, parallax

The parallax background is not working in Chrome or Safari on this site: http://www.krjwoodcraft.com

It works fine in Firefox. I cant see anything wrong with the code. Its been driving me crazy for days.

http://krjwoodcraft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try to validate your HTML markup (http://validator.w3.org/) you'll see there are unclosed tags, duplicate IDs... Any of these could be the cause.

Regards,

Jordi

Comment: thanks. I bookmarked that link. I fixed the errors and its still not working in anything other than firefox.

Comment: I've taken a closer look and I think the issue is caused by animate.css. Either update animate.css to a newer version or remove the first style applied to the body. More info: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/commit/f91ff869ded384a5dbcba72c50d2e2b333fac89f

Comment: worked!. I added the change highlighted in the link. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So your parallax background images have a "fixed" background position, and that line in animate.css was breaking it (apparently only in webkit browsers, i.e. safari and chrome). A similar issue: https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/26  That line was added to animate.css at some point to turn on 3D acceleration, but it was removed later as it was causing these issues. You know, weird CSS quirks... :)